# Save KNIME workflow in alternate location

Tags: eclipse, knime

New to KNIME and Eclipse. Using KNIME v3.2.1 in Eclipse v4.5. When I create a new KNIME workflow (or Workflow group), these are being saved to a workspace called `LOCAL:/` which is set to `C:\Documents and Settings\[ME]\workspace` on my computer.

I need to be able to develop my projects portably on several computers. Is it possible to create a workspace running on a USB (or network drive)? Then on PC-A, the workspace points to `[USB-STICK-ON-PC-A]\[SOME-PATH]` and similarly on PC-B.

This would allow me to work on my KNIME projects on PC-A, save and walk away. Later, when I opened KNIME on PC-B I could just carry on where I left off (assuming the USB stick came with me from PC-A!).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, you can start KNIME (eclipse) with any workspace (even relative to the installation). In case you decided to not ask for the location of the workflow on startup, you can start with the default workflow and switch (`File` | `Switch Workspace` | ...) workspace from there. That can be `./knime-workspace` for example for a relative path, `//network-share/your/path/to/a/workspace` or on a (network) drive: `X:/workflows/w0`.

(It is also possible to start to a new/old workspace using the `-data` command line option.)

You can refer to the workflowrelative paths in the workflow using the URL syntax: `knime://knime.workflow/relativeToWorkflow`. (This is not supported by all nodes, but more-and-more nodes support it.)

Comment: Great, have tried your suggestion and this works! Is there any way to have multiple workspaces? A small `bug` (or feature-request?) is that this re-configures Eclipse and (as far as I could see) resets all my user-selected preferences (eg. `General > Appearance > Theme`). Better would be to allow multiple workspaces. That way you could use a local workspace for fast, possibly temporary work, and a relative/network/USB workspace for work that needed to be portable. Not sure if that is an Eclipse or KNIME problem.

Comment: Yes, you can have as many workspace as many you want (and your quota/ssd allows). You can even import the same workflows/projects to the new workspaces. I would recommend creating a base (empty) workspace you can copy to each location and switch to the copy, but you can also export and import the Preferences (`File` | `Import Preferences...`/`Export Preferences...`.).

Comment: Can you have multiple workspaces visible, though? When I create a new workspace, I do note that under `Window > Preferences > General > Startup and Shutdown > Workspaces` my two workspaces (one local and one of the USB stick) are listed. I also note that I can select `Prompt for workspace on startup` which works as expected...but I cannot get Eclipse/KNIME to show me both workspaces at the same time. Maybe its not possible, seems like this would be a useful feature.

Comment: You can start multiple instances of KNIME/eclipse, so yes it is possible. (Though I guess it is not recommended to share projects in multiple open workspaces.)